# How to skip/subtract first value in foreach loop codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

This is in my view:

```
<?php foreach ($serial_items as $k => $v): ?>
    <?php foreach ($v['children'] as $a => $b): ?>
    <li>
        <span class="info-bold" style="font-size:12px;"><?=$b->serial_num?></span>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?> 
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Q: how can skip first value in `$v`? or I want to start the loop from 2nd up to last item of `$v`.

Comment: Suggestion #1: `<?php array_shift($serial_items); foreach ($serial_items as $k => $v): ?>`

Comment: Suggestion #2: `foreach (array_slice($serial_items,1) as $k => $v): ?>`

Comment: Suggestion #3: `<?php foreach ($serial_items as $k => $v): if ($k > 0) { ?>`

Comment: Please do not provide resolving advice as a comment.  If the question is "too easy", then it's probably a duplicate which should be closed.  Future researchers should not be sifting through comments for solutions (which cannot be downvoted). Please respect Stack Overflow page design.

Comment: I do see any advantage is bloating the html document with `<span>` tags.  Just apply your styling to the `<li>` elements.  If you never use `$k` or `$a`, then don't declare them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it will be a good solution or not, but it will work for you.

```
<?php foreach ($serial_items as $k => $v): ?>
         <?php $counter =0;  foreach ($v['children'] as $a => $b): ?>
              <?php if($counter == 0) continue; //if counter is 0, it means you are at first value of $v array, so skip it and continue the loop ?>
              <li>
                 <span class="info-bold" style="font-size:12px;"><?=$b->serial_num?></span>
              </li>
         <?php $counter++; ?>
         <?php endforeach; ?>
```

As you can see i have created a counter variable $counter in the top foreach loop, where its value is 0. Now in the second loop, i check if $counter is equal to 0, if zero, it means i am at first element of $v array, so it skips it and continue to the inner loop by using **continue** . $counter is incremented with each iteration of inner foreach loop and is set to zero again with each iteration of outer foreach loop.

I hope this will help.

**Note: This code i not tested, it is just to give you an idea. It may or may not work. Kindly adjust it according to your needs if you are using it**

Comment: I do not endorse running n times m conditions.  You are making unnecessary iterated comparisons and needlessly maintaining a counter.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php foreach ($serial_items as $k => $v): ?>
<?php $i=0;?>
<?php foreach ($v['children'] as $a => $b): ?>
 <?php if($i>0){?>
<li>
    <span class="info-bold" style="font-size:12px;"><?=$b->serial_num?></span>
</li>
<?php $++;}?>
<?php endforeach; ?> 
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Errm... `$++`?  There are several undesirable aspects of this post.